# "Incorrect" derivation for sum of infinite natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, divergent-series

I am trying to derive sum of infinite natural numbers for which the established answer is $-1/12$ but I am getting $-1/6$ as my answer and am unable to figure out what exactly am I doing wrong. Probably something very silly or something very fundamental is wrong in my derivation. The way I proceed is:$$S = 1+2+3+4+5+6...$$  $$=> S = 1+3+5+7+9+... + 2+4+6+8+10+...$$  $$=> S = 1+3+5+7+9+... +2(1+2+3+4+5+...)$$  $$=> S = 1+3+5+7+9... + 2S$$  $$=>-S = 1+3+5+7+9...$$  shifting RHS a position to the right and adding to itself:  $$-2S = 1+4+8+12+16+...$$  $$=>-2S = 1+4(1+2+3+4+5...)$$  $$-2S = 1+ 4S$$  which results in $S=-1/6$. It would be nice if someone can tell me which step of derivation is wrong and why is it wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If writing in such fashion were completely legitimate, then there'd be no problem in your computation. The genuine problem is that such manipulations of not-convergent series are not at all guaranteed to produce legitimate/correct outcomes. Indeed, your manipulation in the same spirit as other things on-line shows that it is possible to obtain many different "sums" for the same (not-convergent) series.

Comment: @paulgarrett To make this a little bit more concrete : Riemann's theorem states that a convergent alternating series , which is not absolute converging, can be arranged in such a way that it converges to ANY given real number $r$. This is not exactly the case here because $1-2+3-4+\cdots$ is not convergent either, but it shows that care is needed, if we work with infinite sums.

Comment: @Peter, yes, indeed, we could say that already with _convergent_, but only _conditionally_ convergent series, there's a huge problem. So... no wonder.

Comment: Isn't it self-contradictory to say that the series is divergent and that it has a finite sum? I am building on the assumption that $-1/12$ is the correct answer, and my objective is to compute that. Which would make me think (as a novice mathematician) that I can play around like any other series. How do I combine the facts that there is a finite answer to the sum and that this is divergent series?

Comment: Right, a divergent series does not have a finite sum in any simple or ordinary sense. To produce a finite number attached to it, with some reasonable sense, requires one of a number of things called "summation methods". You can google "Euler summation" and "Abel summation", and so on. These things are not completely elementary, but give vastly more explanation of the "how" of such paradoxical summations than otherwise-simple manipulations. But, unsurprisingly, simple (possibly misleading) manipulations are easy to "sell". :)

Comment: @ManishGoel We don't say that a divergent series has a finite sum, rather that it can be regularized to a particular value, for example, your sum can be zeta regularized to give $-1/12$.  As paulgarrett mentions, do not follow such algebraic manipulations of such series, regardless of what you see on YouTube.  MrYouMath has a nice video explaining the difference between the false '1+2+3+...=-1/2` and the correct connections to things like the Riemann zeta function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$A  = S-S = 1+(2-1)+(3-2)+(4-3)+\ldots = 1+1+1+1+\ldots$$
But $$n+A = (\underbrace{1+\ldots+1}_n)+1+1+1+1+\ldots= 1+1+1+1+\ldots= A$$
hence assigning a value to such divergent series is inconsistent and from $A= A+1$ you can obtain the value you'd like :

$$S = S+c(A-A) = S+c(A+1)-cA =S+c + c(A-A)= S+c$$

Now if you consider instead some [divergent series summation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Abelian_means), for example
$$T = \lim_{z \to 1^-} \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k k z^k$$ it becomes different and you get a consistent value for $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice, convergent series:

$$
\begin{align}1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots & =\underbrace{1-\frac12-\frac14}_{1\text{ odd, }2\text{ evens}}+\frac13-\frac16-\frac18+\dots \\
& =\underbrace{\left(1-\frac12\right)-\frac14}_{1\text{ odd, }2\text{ evens?}}+\left(\frac13-\frac16\right)-\frac18+\dots \\
& =\frac12-\frac14+\frac16-\frac18+\dots\tag{calculate parenthesis?} \\
& =\frac12\left(1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots \right)
\end{align}$$

But wait a minute?!?  Clearly the original series is larger than $0$,

$$\left(1-\frac12\right)+\left(\frac13-\frac14\right)+\dots>0?$$

But less than $1$,

$$1+\left(-\frac12+\frac13\right)+\left(-\frac14+\frac15\right)+\dots<1? $$

But we just showed above that

$$1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots =\frac12\left(1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots \right)?$$

So the sum exists and is equal to half of itself?

---

Bonus points if you can figure out why.

Comment: in human language, you wrote that (formally) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2(2n-1)} - \frac{1}{4n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2(2n-1)} - \frac{1}{4n} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$

Comment: I don't have a strict mathematical proof that I am confident about but I have some logical ideas. Firstly, there is an accumulation of odd numbers, and calculation is biased as more even numbers are used. Secondly (and more importantly), changing the order of series maybe changing its nature. In third step you write, $1/2 - 1/4 + 1/6 - 1/8$, pairing two digits and calculating gives $1/4 + 1/24 + 1/60 ...$ which I think is divergent. Let me know how incorrect I am :D

Comment: @ManishGoel Yes, you are pretty much right.  The point is to show that basic arithmetic does not work with infinite series, even (conditionally) convergent ones.  An extreme cases is adding a single $+0$ into the series can change its value.  Taking a quick look at $1/4+1/24+1/60+\dots$, you should actually get $\frac12\ln(2)$.  ;)

Comment: @user1952009 pft, human language?  What is that?  :D

Comment: @ManishGoel changing the order of summation as you want is allowed only for absolutely convergent series. You should prove that from any conditionally (but not absolutely) convergent series (of real numbers), for any real number $a$ number there is a reordering of the series whose limit is $a$. Hence reordering a conditionally convergent series yields a completely different series.

Comment: @user1952009 Riemann's theorem says we can even make the series divergent.

Comment: @SimpleArt making it divergent is obvious, making it convergent to any desired value too by the way.